# Kendo Jquery Spreadsheet component and Treeview component with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

We are using Kendo Jquery Spreadsheet component and Treeview component in one of our web application. Now we have planned to migrate our web application to Angular(2+).

Now we need know whether existing Kendo Jquery Spreadsheet and Treeview component will work with Angular(2+) + Angular Material Design?

If the jquery components works, is it possible to get any sample code?

Thanks 
Previn S

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the jquery components but there will be many things you'll have to do to make it work. This includes calling `markForCheck` of the change detector at times and refreshing the kendo component when different Angular events occur since the jquery components don't communicate with Angular2 at all.

You can read a guide about integrating your components [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

TreeView is already in [the development channel](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/installation/development-builds/):

[TreeView docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/treeview/)